# Hibernate criteria. Select by alias

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cash")
public class CashItem extends Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "cash_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cash_seq_gen", sequenceName = "cash_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="object_id")
    private Long objectId = 1l;

    @Column(name="object_type")
    private Long objectType = 1l;
```

And the link table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cash_to_order")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CashToOrderItem extends Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "cash_to_order_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cash_to_order_seq_gen", sequenceName = "cash_to_order_seq")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private OrderItem order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cash_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private CashItem cash;
```

I get Criteria from CashToOrderItem and wanna make next query

```
criteria.createAlias("cash","c1");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c1.objectType",ocf.getCounterparty()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("с1.objectId",ocf.getSubCounterparty()));
```

But error occured what ***could not resolve property: с1 of: CashToOrderItem*** if i added two or more Restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating criteria on CashToOrder, please reach out to cash from that class for alias. i.e. cashToOrder.cash

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CashToOrderItem.class, "cashToOrder");
criteria.createAlias("cashToOrder.cash","c1");
```